# Wrong source paths in generated source map

Tags: uglifyjs, source-maps, gulp-uglify

Using [gulp-uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) (which is using [mozilla/source-map](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map)) we're creating a source map. The problem is that all sources are prepended with "app/". Is there anyway to remove this without string replace?

---

We've tried the sourceRoot setting with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and turns out that I had a wrong alias in my localhost Apache configuration; I was pointing to a sub directory `www` while it should be pointing to the parent directory where my `source` and `www` files are!